# Why is this an infinite loop, how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to make a 1-100 guess game in JavaScript but it keeps crashing. I suppose that I made an infinite loop without knowing it. How can I fix it?

```
var generator = function(input, rand, number, tries){
    rand = 100*Math.random();
    number = Math.ceil(rand);
    tries = 0;
    
    while (true){
        if (input > number){
            console.log("Ο αριθμός που έδωσες είναι μεγαλύτερος από αυτόν που σκέφτηκα");
            tries += 1;
            
        } else if (input < number){
            console.log("Ο αριθμός που έδωσες είναι μικρότερος από αυτόν που σκέφτηκα");
            tries +=1;
        } else {
            console.log('Συγχαρητήρια κερδίσατε');
            break;
        }
    }
}
generator(prompt("Δώσε έναν αριθμό"));
```

Comment: `input` nor `number` are changed in the loop, hence they never can be equal, unless they were equal at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're only calling prompt once, that is while calling the function and therefore the input will only be asked **once**.

The corrected code would be something like this

```js
var generator = function(){
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let tries = 0;
    let input;
    // loop will ask for input till the correct answer is found
    while (input = prompt('Enter your guess')){
        if (input > number){
            console.log("guess is greater than number");
            tries++;
            
        } else if (input < number){
            console.log("guess is less than number");
            tries++;
        } else {
            console.log(`you won, took ${tries} tries`);
            break;
        }
    }
}
generator();
```

Comment: This ends the loop when nothing is input, which doesn't appear to be desired in the original code

Answer (score 0):

The following thing happens:
You call the function exactly once by providing it the return-value of "prompt".
From then on the function remains in its while-loop,
because the input is never being reassigned again by a new prompt or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. You should define the answer outside (before) the generator - otherwise, each trip through the generator the number will change, which makes a guessing game not work correctly.
2. Instead of a while loop, call (again) the generator function each time the answer is incorrect.
3. You were defining inputs to your generator function, but not passing anything in. With the variables move outside the function, it is necessary to provide those values.
4. Tries must be a let because we change its value during the program execution. The other variables do not change, so they should be const.
5. I changed the console.log statements to alert statements because in the StackOverflow "StackSnippets" demo, the console logs do not display until everything has completed - so no feedback/progress messages. You can change that back on your system.
6. To make this demo easier to test, I tell the user the answer before they even try to guess. You would remove that, of course.

```js
const rand = 10*Math.random();
const number = Math.ceil(rand);
let tries = 0;
alert(`The answer will be: ${number}`);

var generator = function(input, rand, number, tries){
        tries += 1;
        if (input > number){
            alert("Ο αριθμός που έδωσες είναι μεγαλύτερος από αυτόν που σκέφτηκα");
            if (tries < 7) generator(prompt("Δώσε έναν αριθμό"), rand, number, tries);
        } else if (input < number){
            alert("Ο αριθμός που έδωσες είναι μικρότερος από αυτόν που σκέφτηκα");
            if (tries < 7) generator(prompt("Δώσε έναν αριθμό"), rand, number, tries);
        } else {
            console.log(`Συγχαρητήρια κερδίσατε, after ${tries} tries`);
        }
}
generator(prompt("Δώσε έναν αριθμό"), rand, number, tries);
```